# What's the importance of defining .machine file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on pr2_arm_navigation and there is a launch file that includes another launch file "right_arm_collision_free_ik.launch." In the launch file there is a line as follow:

```
<include file="$(find pr2_machine)/$(env ROBOT).machine" />
```

I would like to know what the .machine file is used for. Is that related to command such as "export ROBOT=sim", which is for the purpose of discrimination of a real physical world Robot and a simulation Robot?

Appreciate for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32331/what%27s-the-importance-of-defining-.machine-file?/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The machine file is a launch file that contains definitions for the two computers on the PR2. It allows for distributing nodes across the two machines by using the machine tag in nodes.

When running in simulation, the user normally wants to launch only on one machine, his own computer. The machine file sim.machine sets both machine definitions (names are c1 and c2) to localhost. pr2.machine adds definitions for the actual machines on the pr2.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0